# Azure DevOps SSIS Build task doesn't produce dtsconfig file

Tags: ssis, azure-pipelines

I have 3 dtsx packages (package deployment model) that are now being locally built in VisualStudio 2019 .

This process produces the 3 files inside the bin/deployment folder,`(.deploymentManifest, .dtsx and .dtsconfig)` ,  needed to install and configure the job steps :

[local bin folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5KHT.png)

The pipeline job builds it in a similar way using `nuget` and `SSIS` Build task.

[pipeline job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO2AQ.png)

But doesn’t produce the `dtsconfig` file

[artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94ARB.png)

I’ve tried using relative path and copying the `dtsconfig` into the folder but the `deploymentManifest` file just don’t have the `ConfigurationFile` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DTSDeploymentManifest GeneratedBy="WIN-1V2BO1VIS10\VssAdministrator" GeneratedFromProjectName="ETL"
 GeneratedDate="2021-10-14T16:21:19.2937202+00:00" AllowConfigurationChanges="true"> 
<Package>Populate_DW_XX.dtsx
</Package> 
</DTSDeploymentManifest>
```

Comment: I've tried using environment variables in package configuration with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the configuration string would need to have the same value on the azure agent. Reading around, it looks like the only way to do this is using environment variables

Answer (score 0):

Add this node into your root `<project>` node .dtproj file :

```
<Miscellaneous>
  <ProjectItem>
    <Name>myFile.dtsConfig</Name>
    <FullPath>myFile.dtsConfig</FullPath>
  </ProjectItem>
</Miscellaneous>
```

Or you can use this documentation (Enable package configurations) :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-5-2-enabling-and-configuring-package-configurations?view=sql-server-ver16#enable-package-configurations